# Network inspector not able to catch Network request - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, fiddler, ktor

I have used ktor CIO engine to make API calls. When I am trying to check network calls but URLs are not showing inside Android studio Network inspection. Performance testing team tried to intercept API calls using Fiddler tool but they are also unable to capture API calls.

Do I have to change any settings inside App.

I have added **cleartextTrafficPermitted** as true for testing for both System and Users.

```
 <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
        <certificates src="user" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
```

I tried adding cleartextTrafficPermitted inside AndroidManifest file also for testing. But nothing seems to work. Am I missing anything here?

**Ktor implementation as below:**

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideHttpClient(): HttpClient = HttpClient(CIO) {

    expectSuccess = false
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        gson()
    }

    install(Logging) {
        logger = Logger.DEFAULT
        level = LogLevel.ALL
    }
    
    install(HttpTimeout) {
        requestTimeoutMillis = 120000
        connectTimeoutMillis = 120000
        socketTimeoutMillis = 120000
    }

    engine {
        https {
            trustManager = @SuppressLint("CustomX509TrustManager")
            object : X509TrustManager {
                @SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
                override fun checkClientTrusted(p0: Array<out X509Certificate>?, p1: String?) {
                }

                @SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
                override fun checkServerTrusted(p0: Array<out X509Certificate>?, p1: String?) {
                }

                override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate>? = null
            }
        }
    }

    HttpResponseValidator {
        validateResponse { response: HttpResponse ->
            val statusCode = response.status.value

            println("HTTP status: $statusCode")

            when (statusCode) {
                in 300..399 -> throw RedirectResponseException(response, statusCode.toString())
                in 400..499 -> throw ClientRequestException(response, statusCode.toString())
                in 500..599 -> throw ServerResponseException(response, statusCode.toString())
            }

            if (statusCode >= 600) {
                throw ResponseException(response, statusCode.toString())
            }
        }

        handleResponseExceptionWithRequest { cause, request ->
            println("HTTP status: $cause")
            throw cause
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the Network inspector catch requests from another client, e.g., https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection?

Comment: I have not checked that @AlekseiTirman. as in my app I am not using HttpURLConnection. But Fiddler tool also not able to capture the requests, that is why I am thinking there might be some setting issue.

Comment: Please check it to determine if that's a client-dependent issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and saw network requests in my network inspector

```
NetworkClient().httpClient {
        defaultRequest {
            url {
                protocol = URLProtocol.HTTPS
                host = provideServerUrl(get())
            }
        }
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(
                Json {
                    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                    prettyPrint = true
                    classDiscriminator = "class"
                }
            )
        }
        install(Logging) {
            logger = Logger.DEFAULT
            level = LogLevel.ALL
        }
    }
}
```

That network client is

```
expect class NetworkClient() {
fun httpClient(config: HttpClientConfig<*>.() -> Unit): HttpClient
}
```

and android-side implementation in KMM is:

```
    actual class NetworkClient actual constructor() {
    actual fun httpClient(config: HttpClientConfig<*>.() -> Unit): HttpClient {
        return HttpClient(OkHttp) {
            config(this)
            install(Logging){
                logger = object: Logger {
                    override fun log(message: String) {
                        Log.v("HTTP Client", message)
                    }
                }
                level = LogLevel.ALL
            }
            engine {
                config {
                    retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I can't change CIO engine to Okhttp engine. Is there any issue with CIO engine?